# Laptop screen works until login - second screen works after that

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Problem is as stated in the title. When I safe load using the motherboard graphics the screen works throughout login and after.

When I use my nvidea drivers (nvidea-418) the laptop screen works until I login, after I hit enter on my password it freezes around a tenth of a second later, and then my external monitor kicks in.

The whole xorg log file is too big to paste, but what I believe contains the relevant parts are:

```
[   239.369] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-2609.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[   239.370] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   239.370] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-143-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[   239.370] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu 5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019 x86_64
[   239.370] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=1cecb776-9479-4233-9676-d8d303f4c25d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[   239.370] Build Date: 03 April 2019  09:03:57AM
[   239.370] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   239.370] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[   239.370]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   239.370] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   239.371] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon May  6 11:34:50 2019
[   239.371] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   239.371] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   239.373] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   239.373] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   239.373] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   239.374] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[   239.374] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   239.374] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   239.374] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   239.374] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   239.374] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   239.374] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   239.374] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   239.374] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   239.374]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   239.374] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   239.374]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   239.374] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   239.374]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   239.374] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   239.374]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   239.374] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   239.374]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   239.374] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   239.374] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   239.375] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   239.375] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[   239.375] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[   239.375] (II) Loader magic: 0x5575291c1020
[   239.375] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   239.375]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   239.375]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   239.375]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   239.375]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   239.376] (++) using VT number 2

[   239.379] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_35
[   239.380] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   239.382] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 12 paused 0
[   239.382] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   239.384] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 13 paused 0
[   239.387] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   239.387] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" ModulePath extended to "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   239.387] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" setting /dev/dri/card1 as PrimaryGPU
[   239.390] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:0) 8086:591b:1558:9501 rev 4, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/536870912, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   239.390] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:1ba1:1558:9501 rev 161, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   239.390] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   239.392] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   239.394] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   239.394]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   239.394]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   239.394] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   239.394] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[   239.398] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   239.398]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   239.399]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   239.399] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  418.56  Fri Mar 15 12:37:35 CDT 2019
[   239.399] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   239.400] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:1
[   239.401] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   239.401] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   239.402] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   239.403] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   239.403]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   239.403]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   239.403] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[   239.403] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[   239.403] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[   239.404] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   239.404]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   239.404]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   239.404] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[   239.404] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[   239.404] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[   239.405] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   239.405] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[   239.405] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   239.405] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   239.406] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card1
[   239.406] (II) Applying OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" options to /dev/dri/card1
[   239.406] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
[   239.406] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
[   239.406] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[   239.406] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[   239.406] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[   239.407] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[   239.434] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   239.434]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[   239.434]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   239.434] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  418.56  Fri Mar 15 12:36:35 CDT 2019
[   239.462] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[   239.462] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0 (boot)
[   239.462] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[   239.462] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[   239.462] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[   239.462] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[   239.464] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design (GP104-A) at
[   239.464] (II) NVIDIA(0):     PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[   239.464] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 8388608 kBytes
[   239.464] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 86.04.6e.00.12
[   239.464] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C34J79x (DFP-0): connected
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C34J79x (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C34J79x (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   239.494] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   239.499] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[   239.499] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[   239.499] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[   239.499] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[   239.500] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[   239.500] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[   239.500] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 3440 x 1440
[   239.511] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (109, 110); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[   239.512] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[   239.512] (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[   239.512] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[   239.537] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[   239.571] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[   239.571] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[   239.571] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   239.571] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[   239.572] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "PrimaryGPU" is not used
[   239.572] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   239.572] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   239.572] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   239.572] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   239.572] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[   239.572] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   239.572] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   239.572] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   239.572] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   239.573] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[   239.574] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   239.574] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   239.575] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[   239.575] (II) GLX: Another vendor is already registered for screen 0
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension NV-GLX
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension NV-CONTROL
[   239.575] (II) Initializing extension XINERAMA
[   239.625] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[   239.625] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   239.625] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   239.625] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   239.626] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   239.626]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.28.2
[   239.626]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   239.626]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   239.626] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   239.627] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 40 paused 0
[   239.627] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   239.627] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   239.627] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   239.628] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.628] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   239.628] (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
[   239.628] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3"
[   239.628] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   239.628] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   239.628] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   239.638] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.638] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   239.638] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event23)
[   239.638] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   239.638] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[   239.639] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event23 13:87 fd 43 paused 0
[   239.639] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   239.639] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event23"
[   239.639] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   239.640] (II) event23 - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.640] (II) event23 - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   239.640] (II) event23 - Video Bus: device removed
[   239.640] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input31/event23"
[   239.640] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   239.640] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   239.640] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   239.640] (II) event23 - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.640] (II) event23 - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   239.641] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event24)
[   239.641] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   239.641] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[   239.641] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event24 13:88 fd 44 paused 0
[   239.641] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   239.641] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event24"
[   239.641] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   239.642] (II) event24 - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.642] (II) event24 - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   239.642] (II) event24 - Video Bus: device removed
[   239.642] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:12/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input32/event24"
[   239.642] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   239.642] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   239.642] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   239.643] (II) event24 - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.643] (II) event24 - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   239.643] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[   239.643] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   239.643] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   239.643] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 45 paused 0
[   239.643] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   239.643] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[   239.643] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   239.644] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.644] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   239.644] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[   239.644] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[   239.644] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   239.644] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   239.644] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   239.645] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.645] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   239.645] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event2)
[   239.645] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   239.645] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   239.645] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   239.645] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   239.645] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[   239.646] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 46 paused 0
[   239.646] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[   239.646] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[   239.646] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   239.646] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.646] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[   239.646] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[   239.646] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[   239.646] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   239.646] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   239.646] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   239.647] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.647] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[   239.647] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event256)
[   239.647] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   239.647] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   239.647] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event257)
[   239.647] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   239.647] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   239.648] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event258)
[   239.648] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   239.648] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   239.648] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event6)
[   239.648] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   239.648] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Receiver'
[   239.649] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 47 paused 0
[   239.649] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: always reports core events
[   239.649] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[   239.649] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   239.649] (II) event6  - Logitech USB Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.649] (II) event6  - Logitech USB Receiver: device is a keyboard
[   239.649] (II) event6  - Logitech USB Receiver: device removed
[   239.649] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:046D:C53D.0001/input/input13/event6"
[   239.650] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Receiver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   239.650] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   239.650] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   239.650] (II) event6  - Logitech USB Receiver: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   239.650] (II) event6  - Logitech USB Receiver: device is a keyboard
[   239.651] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver Mouse (/dev/input/event7)
[   239.651] (**) Logitech USB Receiver Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   239.651] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Receiver Mouse'
[   239.665] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event7 13:71 fd 48 paused 0
[   239.665] (**) Logitech USB Receiver Mouse: always reports core events
[   239.665] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   239.665] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
```

I'm assuming one of the internal display ports should be reading as connected? Any help as to how to fix or further diagnose is much appreciated

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using? are you using ubuntu desktop? I assume you have checked your display settings?

Comment: Yup - says I have no laptop monitor connected after I login (it works at login screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off with, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, with the most recent drivers available as of today. I have a similar problem with my own *convoluted* setup- I have an HP laptop with a GTX 1060 that I've connected over a mini PCIe to PCIe 1x doodad.  *The laptop itself is physically sideways*, and something about the drivers for my particular laptop makes the screen rotate whenever I flip the laptop sideways (this is helpful in *some* situations, but not many).

In essence, my setup boils down to this:
    Intel integrated graphics on an integrated LVDS panel
    Nvidia GTX 1060 outputting over DVI to an external monitor.

For others who have this issue, please only proceed if you have something similar.  I *don't* know if this will work for you, or if this is even a problem for laptops with AMD GPUs.

## What didn't work for me:

Nvidia has a startup script for their code, which looks like this:
`sh -c '/usr/bin/nvidia-settings --load-config-only'`
I tried doing most of the following with it- that's where this code came from.

#### Using crontab to add nVidia's startup script to the boot sequence, as well as a custom xrandr script to fix the monitor

`crontab -e`, and then adding

```bsh
@reboot sh -c '/usr/bin/nvidia-settings --load-config-only'
```

#### editing `.xinitrc`

```bsh
startx
sh -c '/usr/bin/nvidia-settings --load-config-only'
```

also didn't work.

I also tried modifying basically every rc file that I could get my hands on, and *none* of them worked.

#### Copying monitors.xml to GDM3's config, as per [this stackOverflow answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082234/959727)

This *partially* worked- part of my problem was that my laptop's display *also* wasn't showing up until after I'd logged in- **blindly**- this took more than one try to figure out.

First, go to settings and verify that you have everything set up the way you want it.
*If your setup is anything like mine, the monitors.xml file will only have **one** monitor config in it*

```bsh
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config
```

if you can't even see the login screen, this will help out.

## What *fully* worked:

#### Not using Wayland for the login screen, per [another StackOverflow answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043388/959727)

first, you'll need to do this:

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

find this line *(for me, it's right below `[daemon]`)*:

```bsh
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false
```

and remove the comment, so that it looks like this:

```bsh
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

At this point, you should be able to save your changes and reboot.

#### For people with rotated displays only:

Because my laptop is physically sideways, I also had to:
copy monitors.xml to the GDM's config by doing the steps above- this fixes the orientation at the login screen,
and I put a custom `xrandr` script in `gnome-session-properties` (also called "Startup Applications", it's a GUI ):

```bsh
xrandr --output LVDS-1-1 --rotate left
```

to get my setup fully working.

### *Why* does this work?

I honestly don't know, but I presume that it has something to do with nVidia not adding full Wayland support yet, or something of the like.