# ACPI error, ubuntu wont boot

Tags: acpi

Right now I am faced with the problem that Ubuntu won't boot. I am currently using my Dell computer as a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Windows works perfectly so far only when I start Ubuntu I get the following error message at some point after a black screen.

```
[1745.965236] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP.GPS.PCGP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-300)
[1745.965264] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP.GPS due to previous error, AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-529)
[1745.965269] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP._DSM due to previous error, AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-529)
```

Until yesterday everything was still running perfectly, then I connected a docking station at work, which is connected to two monitors. When I wanted to change the resolution/scaling of the screens, the computer crashed.

If I set acpi = off in the grub, the boot process starts, but I have no access to my Nvidia graphics card that I depend on. In addition, the computer then runs very slowly and the cursor is kinda laggy.

I'm not very familiar with ubuntu yet, maybe someone can help me at this point.
In addition to the Nvidia RTX 2060, the Dell also has an Intel UHD GPU. As CPU it uses a i9-10885H Intel Core.

Thanks

Comment: If you can edit grub at boot time, use this instead of acpi-off `acpi_enforce_resources=lax pcie_ports=compat`

Comment: Still wont boot

Comment: Can you run `mokutil --sb-state`  to confirm that secure boot is off please?`

Comment: Did this and it says that the secure boot is disabled

Comment: I you remove the `acpi` line and add `nomodeset` to grub will it boot then? you wont have nvidia drivers but it will let us know if the 2 monitors via the docking station is the problem.

Comment: still wont boot with the same error message

Comment: The acpi BIOS error is the one I have never seen before. I found some info here but no real fixes however. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031601/problem-with-dual-monitor-config-in-ubuntu-18-04 **or this one specific to Dell** https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/External-Monitor-not-working-Ubuntu-nvidia/td-p/6241315 and it's worth figureing out if you are booting with wayland enabled.

Comment: thanks for the research, I couldnt find any answers either. 
I'll see if these forum posts can still help me somehow.